# How can I possibly avoid infinite loop in this Java server?

Tags: java, loops, optimization, infinite-loop

I am not talking about threading or anything to make this more complicated.
Most server programs I saw are like this or while(true){...} (same concept).

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TCPServer {
    ServerSocket welcomeSocket;
    public TCPServer(int port) throws IOException {
        welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    }

    public void go() throws IOException {
        // This is not a valid way to wait for a socket connection, You should
        // not have a forever loop or while(true) 
        **for (; ;) {**
            Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
            Scanner clientIn = new Scanner(connectionSocket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream clientOut = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            String clientLine = clientIn.nextLine();
            String modLine = clientLine.toUpperCase();
            clientOut.writeBytes(modLine + "\n");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            TCPServer server = new TCPServer(6789);
            server.go();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Isn't the whole point of a server to indefinitely listen to the clients? Do you just want a good way to close it?

Comment: I thought so too. But I guess my instructor doesn't like infinite loops. Surprisingly I couldn't find any server without an infinite loop yet.

Comment: Why not simply add a condition to exit the loop. Like a boolean that would be true until the server gets a message to end the connection?

Answer (score 2):

It is not looping permanently, your code blocks on line `welcomeSocket.accept()` until someone connects and only after that next lines are executed then it waits for a new connection on `welcomeSocket.accept()`. In other words it loops as many times as it needs( per each connection ).
If you just want to allow only one client to connect, remove `for (; ;)` statement. But it will require to restart your server every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a scheduler with any number of thread in the pool
and prevent the main thread from termination. Here I've used input stream but you can do it in different ways. Here you can use multiple threads to get connections and customize the frequency of the scheduler.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MyTest {

ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);

@Test
public void hello() {
    final Runnable helloServer = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // handle soket connection here
            System.out.println("hadling connection");
        }
    };
    final ScheduledFuture<?> helloHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(helloServer, 1000, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    try {
        System.in.read();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `while(!finished)` option might be a better solution than the "empty" `for` loop. When the exit event occurs, you just set finished to `true`.